# Php break or split a big ICS file

Tags: php, icalendar

I have an ICS file which is 2gb in size and i want to parse ics data from that file but php is not able to read such big file and i am getting fatal error of "Out of Memory" even i have set "ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')".
So i want to somehow break or split big ICS file to small file or is there any way to read the data from such big ICS file.

I have some small files and all are working fine and i can extract data from other files but 2gb big ICS file is more important for me to extract / parse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so don't read it all at once. parse it line-by-line until you reach an "end of record". then you know you've got a complete record read, and can do process it.

Comment: your idea sounds good. Can you provide some example to read this big ICS file line by line?

Comment: `$fh = fopen(...); while($line = fgets($fh)) { ... do stuff ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Usual method to handle `Out of memory` exception is by allocating more ram to php in `php.ini` file but because you have a file of 2Gb thats not a valid option unless you have a lot of memory on your system. Basically you are trying to read the file wrong. Rather than reading the whole file and saving it to a variable which would cost ram equivalent to the size of file, you ran parse them by line or byte depending on the format of file you are working on. Here is a basic example that you can work on

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("fileName", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process line here
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // handle file read error
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yup to read a big file cost more ram to system. So finally i break 2bg ICS file to small ones with 1000lines each and now i have around 3000 split files of big one. Anyways thanks for the help :)